# HTML single Checkbox: Best practise whether to use value attribute or not

Tags: html, servlets, checkbox

today i had a discussion with my colleague. The question was whether to use the additonal value attribute for a **single** HTML checkbox or not.

My preffered way is using a single checkbox **without** a additional value attribute and in backend doing a check like if

```
if (request.getParameter(checkboxName) != null)) {
...
}
```

My colleague argues that is would be more transparent using a single checkbox **with** a additonal checkbox value attribute like value="true" and doing a backend check like

```
if (Boolean.valueOf(request.getParameter(checkboxName))) {
...
}
```

As we want to make a small convention about our internal checkbox handling im now trying to find a "best practise" but couldn't find yet. I saw so far only examples with multiple checkbox with the same name. In this case of course it makes sense for me to use different values.

For me it seems to be a bit overhead using a value attribute in case of a **single** checkbox since i get always a String with "on" if its activated/checked.

We are using a Java Servlet/JSP MVC environment and im not 100% sure if this "on" comes from  [ServletRequest.getParameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: "on" is the default HTML sends as the value for a checkbox.

Comment: From SEO and Wc3 standards perspective, I think it is a safe bet to use the value attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I see reasons for following either method, which means there's probably no noticable difference between them. Whichever you pick will work out fine; just make sure you pick one. You could flip a coin or do a thumbwar or something.

As long as a single approach is consistently used, both will work. Yours is less code and doesn't require boolean conversion, the other´s html is more consistent with multiple checkboxes but will also break if you put the wrong value for whatever reason.

You could always do a bit of both and insert values in html for clarity but check for != null in the code and get the best of both options.

Comment: Thx for the hint of the (maybe only in my eyes) unnecessarily boolean conversion.

Answer (score 1):

It makes no difference server-side as long as you are not checking the parameter for having a *specific* value. By [HTML5 definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#checkbox-state-%28type=checkbox%29), which just establishes the longstanding practice as the rule, a checkbox element has the value `on` by default. This means that your server-side code cannot distinguish between data coming from `<input type=checkbox name=foo>` and data coming from `<input type=checkbox name=foo value=on>`.

Comment: Thx for sharing the link with the official docs for this "on".